# Havit HV-F2060 cooling pad with six small and (normally) very quiet cooling fans us suddenly making noise

Tags: laptop, cooling, cooling-pad, laptop-cooler

I have a Havit HV-F2060 cooling pad with six small and (normally) very quiet cooling fans. Lately whenever I first turn it on, one of the fans begins making an obnoxious buzzing sound like the cooling pad is full of angry bees or something.

Taking it apart for cleaning does nothing to resolve the issue. Smacking it out of frustration seems to make it stop, but I don't want to end up breaking something. What could be the cause of this sound and how might I be able to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience, I would imagine that this is a bad ball bearing in one of the fans. Cleaning/beating it up can only go so far, as eventually the fan and bearing will move back to the position that was making noise.

This occurred on an old PC case of mine, with both intake fans. They would grind, typically when the machine was coming from a cold boot, and smacking the case only did so much. The only real option is replacement of that fan, or the pad itself. Check to see if you're still on warranty or if the company offers replacement DIY fans.

Answer (score 0):

The fans used are similar, if not the same, as those used inside computers.

Most of these fans have friction bearings (only super expensive have ball bearings). The friction bearings can get dry and begin to make noise. To fix it, you either can lube the bearing or replace the fan.

Obviously, a drop of 3-in-1 oil is much cheaper than purchasing a new fan (you can use a drop of cooking oil if nothing else is available).

You will need to access the center of the fan where the blades attach. Remove any labels and/or access cover and place a small drop of oil on the shaft end.

[image]

Complete instructions [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/quiet-noisy-computer-fans-with-a-drop-of-oil/).

If oiling doesn't fix it, replace the fan.